# zend 1.5 registory not working

Tags: php, caching, zend-framework

I have service in zend and I want to use registry for save sql requests all the time for fetch data.

```
 $r = \Zend_Registry::isRegistered('somedata');
        if($r) {
            $somedata = \Zend_Registry::get('somedata');
            echo $r.'yes';
        }else {
            $results = $this->getCurlRequest('abc', 'abc', null);
            \Zend_Registry::set('somedata',$results);
            $somedata = $results;
            echo $r.'no';
        }
```

It is coming all the time in else condition. I do not know why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically \Zend_Registry scope is within current request so you need to use Zend_Session for it.

```
    if (Zend_Session::namespaceIsset('globalvars')) {
        $globalSess = Zend_Session::namespaceGet('globalvars');
    } else {
        $globalSess = new Zend_Session_Namespace('globalvars');
    }
    if (isset($globalSess->yourkey)) {
        echo 'Yes its is already there';
    } else {
        echo 'No it was not but setting it now';
       $globalSess->yourkey = 'Your Value';
    }
```

Comment: we should add at top  session_start();